# Xpath: To fetch attribute from parent node and child node

Tags: xml, xpath

I have below xml:

```
<SESSION DESCRIPTION ="" ISVALID ="YES" MAPPINGNAME ="testing" NAME ="s_testing" REUSABLE ="YES" SORTORDER ="Binary" VERSIONNUMBER ="1
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Commit Interval" VALUE ="10000"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Commit On End Of File" VALUE ="YES"/>
    <METADATAEXTENSION COMPONENTVERSION ="1000000" DATATYPE ="STRING" DESCRIPTION ="" DOMAINNAME ="User Defined Metadata Domain" ISCLIENTEDITABLE ="YES" ISCLIENTVISIBLE ="YES" ISREUSABLE ="NO" ISSHAREREAD ="NO" ISSHAREWRITE ="NO" MAXLENGTH ="256" NAME ="TESTING" VALUE ="TEST" VENDORNAME ="INFORMATICA"/>
</SESSION>
```

I want to fetch name of session(parent node) and name of metadataextension(child node) using xpath. Only 1 or 2 among all sessions have a child node "metadataextension". Appreciate answers in both xpath 1.0 and 2.0

NB: I'm new to XML and XPath and only language I know SQL. Apologies if my question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
//METADATAEXTENSION/../@NAME|//METADATAEXTENSION/@NAME
```

Comment: Thanks :) Now I'm getting below result

Comment: Attribute='NAME=s_testing'

Attribute='NAME=TESTING'

Comment: I'm only getting only session names that has a  metadataextension. But I'm getting the result in 2 separate lines. Is it possible to get the result in one single line like " Session : <session_name> ; Metadataextension : <metadataextension> "